# C++ - Test if a DLL exists to conditional run certain functions

Tags: c++, dll

I have an application that I want to distribute to two sets of customers:
1) a full version that calls functions from a third party library, and
2) a limited version that disables those calls.

I would like to avoid having separate builds and simply distribute the executable to all and include the DLL only for customers that pay for the extra features in the third party library.

However, when I build with the library included, the application will not run if the DLL can't be found.

Is it possible to test if the DLL exists at runtime prior to DLLMAIN being called?

Comment: [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) – and then `GetProcAddress()` of the functions you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by the following way

```
LPCWSTR dllName = helper::developer::getDllPath();
HINSTANCE dynamicLib = LoadLibraryW(dllName);

if (dynamicLib)
{

}
```